# Using a ImageAdapter in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I'm trying to create a memory game - where I have 5x5 images on the screen and the user has to match the images.
I've been using a GridView and populate it with images using a ImageAdapter.
The game works something like this:
 - when a user matches 2 images - the images remain on the screen
 - when a user fails to match the 2 pictures - the imagess changes back to the question-mark.
The problem is that I can't manage to keep the pictures previously matched on the screen - when I use the notifyDataSetChanged() method - all the screen is filled again with question marks.
Here's my code:

// getView method in ImageAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
     ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        {
            if(mThumbIds[i].equals(R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.q_mark);
        }
        return imageView;
}
```

// the onClickListener when a user selects 1 image

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            i++;
            Toast.makeText(easyGame.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ImageView imgV=(ImageView)v;

            if(i%2!=0)
            {

                firstClick=position;
                imgV.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[firstClick]);

            }
            else
            {   
                secondClick=position;
                imgV.setImageResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[secondClick]);
            }

            if(i%2==0)
            {

            if(!(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[firstClick].equals(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[secondClick])))
            {
                Toast.makeText(easyGame.this, "Great!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[firstClick]=ImageAdapter.mThumbsIdsDone[0];
                ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[secondClick]=ImageAdapter.mThumbsIdsDone[0];
                im.notifyDataSetChanged();
                gridview.setAdapter(im);
                gridview.invalidate();
            }
            }       
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// declare as class variable to keep track of views which should stay visible
private HashSet<Integer> keepVisibleViews = new HashSet<Integer>(25);

//in you on click listener
if(!(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[firstClick].equals(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[secondClick])))
 {
     // ... the rest of your code here
     // keep track of views that should stay visible
     keepVisibleViews.add(firstClick);
     keepVisibleViews.add(secondClick);
 }


// in your getView
// show ? mark if we should, else the picture
if (keepVisibleViews.contains(position)
      setImageResource(ImageAdapter.mThumbIds[secondClick]);
else
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.q_mark);
```